# Running pulseaudio inside docker container to record system audio

Tags: docker, selenium, ffmpeg, pulseaudio

I'm trying to set up a Docker container with Selenium that takes a recording of the browser with system audio using ffmpeg. I've got video working using Xvfb. Unfortunately, on the audio side, it seems to be more tricky.

I thought I would set up a virtual pulseaudio sink inside the container, which would allow me to record its monitor:

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=loopback
pacmd set-default-sink loopback
ffmpeg -f pulse -i loopback.monitor test.wav
```

This works on my host operating system, but when trying to start the pulseaudio daemon in a container, it fails with the following message:

```
E: [pulseaudio] module-console-kit.c: Unable to contact D-Bus system bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

This would seem to be related to a freedesktop service called dbus. I've tried installing it and starting its daemon, but I couldn't seem to get it to work properly.
I couldn't find much information on how to proceed from here. What am I missing for pulseaudio? Perhaps there's an easier way to record the system audio inside a container?

My goal is not to record it from the host operating system, but to play the audio inside the browser and record it all inside the same container.

Comment: This sounds like you need more of the standard Linux desktop environment than normally runs inside a Docker container.  A full virtual machine (with simulated display and audio hardware) running a normal desktop Linux setup might be a better match for this application.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing. But the recoded video has crackles in audio. Did you face this problem, too ?

Comment: @boygiandi I'm facing the same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @David yes. It's because of a looping video in Xvfb. Every time it loop, it make the crackles sound.

Comment: @boygiandi What was the solution you implemented? Any reference/links I can look at?

Also I'm not taking a screengrab using xvfb, only audio recording using default device

Comment: @boygiandi I’m seeing the same issue when trying to do a screen capture with XVFB - I’m not really sure what you mean by the looping bit but wondering if you could share what worked.

Comment: @David were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following solution from [here](https://georgik.rocks/how-to-start-d-bus-in-docker-container/) helped me.

Run following commands as root prior to starting PulseAudio:

```sh
mkdir -p /var/run/dbus
dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I also had to comment out `load-module module-console-kit` from `/etc/pulse/default.pa` as it resulted in `E: [pulseaudio] module-console-kit.c: GetSessionsForUnixUser() call failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit was not provided by any .service files` which is suppose is due to missing the consolekit package. pulseaudio seems to work fine without this module.

Comment: Once `module-console-kit` is disabled, pulseaudio will even run without dbus, though it does spit out quite a few (non-fatal) errors.

Comment: Do you folks have a complete Dockerfile or entrypoint available for reference? @XXLuigiMario

Comment: @slhck mine is here: https://github.com/Envek/dockerized-browser-streamer

Comment: @Envek Thanks! pacmd never worked for me, weird. I found another solution in the answer I gave below.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me on its own. What was needed was a more complex setup which included deleting some pulseaudio directories. The entire solution can be found here: https://superuser.com/a/1545361/48078

Specifically, it needed:

```
RUN adduser root pulse-access
```

And in the entrypoint:

```
rm -rf /var/run/pulse /var/lib/pulse /root/.config/pulse
pulseaudio -D --verbose --exit-idle-time=-1 --system --disallow-exit
```