# Cannot run pulseaudio inside livekit docker

Tags: docker, pulseaudio, livekit

I have a docker container livekit, inside it run 2 command

`rm -rf /var/run/pulse /var/lib/pulse /home/egress/.config/pulse /home/egress/.cache/xdgr/pulse`

`pulseaudio -D --verbose --exit-idle-time=-1 --disallow-exit`

but it stuck at the second command.

But I follow [Running pulseaudio inside docker container to record system audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037579/running-pulseaudio-inside-docker-container-to-record-system-audio)
and  run

`rm -rf /var/run/pulse /var/lib/pulse /root/.config/pulse`

`pulseaudio -D --verbose --exit-idle-time=-1 --system --disallow-exit`

inside livekit container as root user, it works.
How do I modify the docker image or the starting command to make it work? Thanks.